# Split housenumber from Addressfield

Tags: php, mysql, logic

I would like to split a single address field into a street and housenumber field.

This is some example data:

```
Examplestreet 1
Examplestreet 1A
Examplestreet 1 B
The Examplest street 2
1st Example street 3A
1st Example street 13 A
```

Now, I was thinking that I start from the right and look for the first number I encounter, then keep going until the first space is encoutered and split there.

You would get something like this:

```
Example:                           1st Example street 13 A
Start from the right:              A
Find the first number:             A 3
Keep going until the first space:  A 31
Split here:                        1st Example Street    |     13A
```

I would like to get this working in mySQL alone, but using PHP is also possible.

When you know a better approach for this, I would like to know to.

I started looking at SUBSTRING_INDEX, but that didn't do the trick.

Frankly I haven't got a clue where to start.

Comment: A good starting point in your case would be to store the house number the way you want it as it is going into the database.  Even if you have to use PHP to process the split before hand, you can do it once instead of every time you select the data later on.

Comment: Is it true, that you house number is always at the end of the string, starting from the digit?

Comment: @Crackertastic This is because of a patch I am writing to convert the old data to the new columns. I recently added the houseNumber column in the database and all the new data is inserted in two columns. The old data has to be converted.

Comment: @user4035: Yes I took a quick look at the data and it seems to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the house number is always at the end of the string, starting from the digit, we can use a regexp:

```
<?php
$names = array(
    'Examplestreet 1',
    'Examplestreet 1A',
    'Examplestreet 1 B',
    'The Examplest street 2',
    '1st Example street 3A',
    '1st Example street 13 A ',
    );

foreach($names as $value)
{
    $matches = array();
    if (preg_match('/.*\s(\d.*)/', $value, $matches))
    {
        print $matches[1]."\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
1A
1 B
2
3A
13 A
```